# How to make a QVBoxLayout available globally

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a QVBoxLayout available globally in Qt. I cannot access it from any other functions.

```
 void MainWindow::on_actionF451_triggered()
{
    QVBoxLayout *compLay = new QVBoxLayout(ui->scrollArea);
```

I have created it in this function then below have added tons of widgets, but need to be able to clear these widgets in another function.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to store the widgets in a container like `QList`. Also what you want is not to make `comPlay` available globally, you want to make it a member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a variable `compLay` to be accessed anywhere in your `MainWindow` class, then define it in `mainwindow.h`'s definition of `MainWindow` class (after Q_OBJECT macro) like this: `QVBoxLayout *compLay;`

and you can change `compLay` within `MainWindow` class however you like:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionF451_triggered(){
  compLay = new QVBoxLayout(ui->scrollArea);
```

or you can make return type of `void MainWindow::on_actionF451_triggered()` not `void`, but `QVBoxLayout *` and return your layout directly (but you will need to correct the connect statement then (i assume, that you don't have one and it is autoconnected) and connect it to slot, where you will need this layout to clean or modify or remember )